# how the custom fields can be viewed in Kibana as a standard type instead of unknown type?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-7, kibana-7

I am using Kibana and elasticsearch version 7.9.1. I have created a pipeline, mapping and index with custom fields. The field type **keyword** converted into "**sting**" but the **custom fields** converted as "**unknown**" type. These unknown types are not listed while creating **visualize** using data table.

My pipeline,

```
 PUT /_ingest/pipeline/test-pipeline
{
  "description": "A pipeline for user data",
  "processors": [
    {
      "my_processor": {
        "field": [
          "my_type:email",
          "my_type:gender"        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My mappings.

```
PUT /test-00/
{
  "mappings": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "last_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "email": {
          "type": "my_type"
        },
        "gender": {
          "type": "my_type"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

My index docs as follows,

```
POST /test2-00/_doc/1?pipeline=test-pipeline
{
  "first_name": "Rahul",
  "last_name": "Sharma",
  "gender": "Male",
  "email": "rahul@example.com"
}

POST /test2-00/_doc/1?pipeline=test-pipeline
{
  "first_name": "Parvindar",
  "last_name": "Singh",
  "gender": "Male",
  "email": "parvindar@example.com"
}
```

1. how the custom fields can be viewed in Kibana as a standard type instead of unknown type?
2. is there a way to list the custom fields as it is in kibana?
   Like if the custom type name is my_string, is it possible to display my_string in kibana?

How to show this as a [image]string?